# How can I determine when all of the resources of an AJAX website have fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, xmlhttprequest, code-injection

I'm looking to inject some pure JavaScript (no jQuery please) into a website to determine when all of the resources (HTML, CSS, scripts, images etc.) have fully loaded. The website uses AJAX, so a simple load event listener isn't enough due to all of the external resources being loaded by XMLHttpRequests.

None of the questions I've found on StackOverflow have been helpful because they all use jQuery and this website does not use jQuery, limiting my approach to pure JavaScript only.

One approach I've considered is tracking when images are done loading but a) I don't know if images loaded via Ajax can be tracked this way and b) I'm not sure how I'd go about tracking this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this. AJAX requests don't even have to load any resources.

Comment: Is there a specific resource you need to wait for? You can test for that.

Comment: @Barmar yes, I'm waiting for a particular json file to be loaded

Comment: You could use `setInterval()` to run a function that periodically checks if the relevant element has been added to the DOM. Or you can use a `MutationObserver`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible.

You cannot know when the code is done loading resources.  At least, not without making assumptions about the site or knowing how it's built.  More AJAX requests can be made at any time by various scripts.  There's no standard for notifying when it's done.